# Will a system clock adjust affect running the stopwatch in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, real-time

Let's say I have `Stopwatch` running in my code and in the middle, some other application has changed the system clock (I have Domain Time on my server syncing every second).

Will it affect the stopwatch result?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, internally Stopwatch relies on Win32 [QueryPerformanceCounter()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644904%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which is not tied to the system clock.

Answer (score 9):

It depends.

`Stopwatch` relies on Win32 [QueryPerformanceCounter()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644904%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) **only** if it is available. This implementation is timechange tolerant.

In case high-resolution counters are not available, `Stopwatch` falls back to system timer, basically `DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks` call. In this unfortunate case `Stopwatch` results will be affected by time(not timezone) changes.

As it is written in cited MSDN article, you can check if high-resolution counters are available using `IsHighResolution` field.

You can blame .Net team using this [won't fix defect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/741848/system-diagnostics-stopwatch-elapsed-time-affected-by-user-changing-computers-date-time) :)

Comment: Details on the QPC usages (or lack of) - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn553408(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

No, it won't affect it.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx):

> The Stopwatch measures elapsed time by counting timer ticks in the underlying timer mechanism. If the installed hardware and operating system support a high-resolution performance counter, then the Stopwatch class uses that counter to measure elapsed time. 
>   Otherwise, the Stopwatch class uses the system timer to measure elapsed time. Use the Frequency and IsHighResolution fields to determine the precision and resolution of the Stopwatch timing implementation.