# how to add Stopwatch in loop

Tags: c#

i'm using while loop, i want to stop looping after 5 min with Stopwatch

```
while (loop)
{
 if (Name == null)
 {
  CheckName = false;
  break;
 }
 else if()//i want to add Stopwatch here
 {
 }
//if Stopwatch finished 
//do something
}
```

i want to loop and then after some time finish the loop to do something else

Comment: There is no reason why Thread.Sleep will break the loop. Without it, you'll most likely freeze your application.

Comment: i'm new in C# so i'm still learn :)

Comment: Are you trying to wait for 5 minutes ? 1- You want to wait for 5 minutes in the else ? 2- you want to start the stopwatch in the else part. And then continue the loop (which might run the else part again) then you would need to recheck if the timer is already started ? 1 or 2. By the way, 2 seems a mess. Why are you exactly doing this ?

Comment: 5 minutes it's example ... i just want loop working check for 2 things `Name==Null` and `stopwatch` to finish .. if `stopwatch` finished i want to do something then `break`

Comment: @CAmrMoneim Check the edited answer below.

Comment: @user3185569 thanks bro

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The classical way is:

```
Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
sw.Start();
while (true)
{ 
    if (Name == null)
    {
       CheckName = false;
       break;
    }
    else if(sw.Elapsed.TotalMinutes >= 5)
    {
       // do something
       // break;
    }
}
sw.Stop();
```

Another way would be:

```
var cancellation = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));
....
else if(cancellation.IsCancellationRequested)
{
    // do something
}
```

I would highly recommend executing this in a background thread using `Task`. A method that runs for 5 mins is going to freeze the UI (If any).

Comment: Note that using `DateTime.Now` means that the loop can be affected by DST changes. Using `DateTime.UtcNow` would avoid that, although it would still be affected by system clock changes. I *suspect* that `Stopwatch` isn't affected by system clock changes.

Comment: thanks bro this really help me :)

Comment: what mean DST Changes?

Comment: @CAmrMoneim Daylight saving time, when the clock advances one hour in some countries in the summer.

Comment: @user3185569 thanks :)

Comment: @CAmrMoneim Use `Stopwatch` like in the edited answer as Jon Suggested.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thank you Jon for that info, that question of relying on `DateTime.Now` was always a concern for me. I was too lazy to google an approach that isn't affected by System Time changing.

Comment: @user3185569 okay i will try it

Comment: @user3185569 worked thanks bro :)

Comment: @JonSkeet Jon you might need to take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27864326/3185569 . It seems that it is not always true, but it is the best approach as it falls back to Utc in the worst case.

Comment: @user3185569 how i can add time into the loop? i tried with this answer and just stay doing things until time finished i just want when time finish do something into the loop

Comment: @CAmrMoneim: It's really unclear what you mean by "stay doing things". It sounds like you need to provide more context - is the problem that you're writing a WinForms/WPF app and you want it to remain responsive during the 5 minutes? If so, you should probably be using a timer of some description.

Comment: answer is working 100% but this not what i need ... i want put time into loop like while (loop)
{
    if (Name == null)
    {
        CheckName = false;
        break;
    }

elso if () // want add time here if time finished just break loop
{}
}

Comment: @user3185569 i really did it but stay doing order into `elso if`

Comment: @CAmrMoneim If the `else` doesn't get executed, then the if condition is `true`. Please edit your answer and show the code you're currently using.

Comment: @user3185569 done

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to do this using `System.Diagnostics.StopWatch`:

```
System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch sw = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
while (sw.Elapsed <= TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5))
{
    if (Name == null)
    {
        CheckName = false;
        break;
    }
}

sw.Stop();
```